# Why does $G(4) >15$ in Waring's problem?

Tags: number-theory

The [Wikipedia page for Waring's Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waring%27s_problem) states that at least sixteen fourth powers are required to sum to any number of the form $31 \times 16^n$. Why is this so?

Comment: take $31$ for instance, the only way to represent $31$ as sum of fourth power numbers is like this $31=2^4+1^4+\cdots+1^4=2^4+15*1^4$. so for $31$ you need at least $16$ fourth power numbers.

Comment: Any fourth power is either $0$ or $1\pmod{16}$. By performing a descent you may easily see that in order to represent $31\cdot 16^n$ you need at least as many terms as the ones needed to represent $31=2^4+1+1+1+\ldots+1$.

Comment: Yes, but it is not clear to me how we would prove the analogous statement for $31\times 2^n$ for larger $n$. @Ahmad

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio Ah, of course. Thank you!

Comment: If you turn that into an answer, I will accept it.